# Android Intent ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT always leads to URI==null despite file being created

Tags: android, android-intent

I try to write a file to a user-defined location using the following intent to receive the file uri

```
    val saveFile = Intent()
    saveFile.action = Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT
    saveFile.type = "application/pdf"
    saveFile.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    saveFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "123.pdf")

    activity.startActivityForResult(saveFile, 123)
```

and then read out the result

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == 123 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && intent != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "URI: ${intent.data}")
    }
    else
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

but the URI is always null even though the intent creates an empty file every time. Filesystem access is granted, as I read files from storage without any problems. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looking at the `data` parameter of `onActivityResult()`. Instead, you are looking at the `Intent` used to create your activity. Replace your second code snippet with:

```kotlin
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == 123 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "URI: ${data.data}")
    }
    else
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

Comment: @GenError: In your defense, this is partially Kotlin's fault. The "turn getters into properties" feature is slick, but it can lead to confusion. In this case, if you had been using `getIntent()` instead of `intent`, the source of the problem would have been more obvious.